# Парсинг html с помощью Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup, синтаксический-анализ

Есть html строка:

```
<p style="text-align: justify;">
    <a href="http://www.postfactum.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/DSC_0320_1.jpg" rel="" style="" target="" title="">
    <img alt="DSC_0320_1" class="alignleft size-medium wp-image-89182" height="163" src="http://www.postfactum.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/DSC_0320_1-300x163.jpg" style="" title="title»" width="300" />
    </a>
    <span style="font-size:14px;">
</p>
```

Нужно получить адрес изображения:http://www.postfactum.ks.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/DSC_0320_1-300x163.jpg. Пытаюсь парсить:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(image_url);

if (doc.select("img[src]").size() > 0) {
    Element image = doc.select("img[src]").get(0);
} else {
    image_url = "null";
}
```

Ошибок нету, но строка пуста. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых вам нужно использовать метод first() или last() в зависимости от порядка елемента. В вашем случае нужно использовать метод first(). `Element image = doc.select("img[src]").first();`. Во-вторых вы не указали атрибут "src": `image_url = image.attr("src");`. Полный код:

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(mage_url);
                    if (doc.select("img[src]").size() > 0) {
                        Element image = doc.select("img[src]").first();
                        image_url = image.attr("src");
                    } else {
                        image_url = "null";
                    }
```

Comment: Спасибо) Выручил.